# scala: any built-in function to divide a double by another double and return quotient and remainder as a tuple

Tags: scala

I can use the following function but is there a better option?

```
    def div(dur:Double) = {
        var days:Int = dur.toInt/24
        var hours:Double = dur%24
        (days, hours)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

works since scala 2.8

```
import scala.math.Integral.Implicits._
val (days, hours) = dur.toInt /% 24
```

Comment: returns hours as Int as well. Possible to get it as double (40.5/24 => 1 and 16.5)

Comment: @sid, most probably not since such operations normally are using with integer type values

Comment: just make your own implicit